# Curl php instagram api

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I try to do request for instagram api, but i get 502 error.

```
POST /v1/media/3_3/likes?access_token=qwerty HTTP/1.1
Host: api.instagram.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP/1.1 502 BAD_GATEWAY
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

But when i do same request from http://www.hurl.it/ i get correct answer. Why?
I make request from the cUrl php, and i get correct answers on other's request.(Like get media).

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @pekka i use this class for requests https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API